# Concatenate variable with string and set it in a new variable

Tags: templates, jinja2

I am trying to set a variable, for example `cmd = "echo 25"`, but it does not work

```
{% set cmd = "echo {{ id }}" %}
```

Please help to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I found ;)

```
{% set cmd = "echo " ~ id %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
{% set testing = 'it worked' %}
{% set another = testing %}
{{ another }}
```

Result:

```
it worked
```

Comment: But it is not a concatenation. How to add a variable to 'it worked'?

Comment: Do you need a view. look this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624520/passing-a-variable-into-a-jinja-import-or-include-from-a-parent-html-file

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the join method to concatenate strings and variables.

```
{% set module = "XYZ" %}
{% set jarfile = [module, '-jar-with-dependencies.jar']|join %}
```